# How to transform a column value into a Index column with its name and a value in python (pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

| Name | Value_1 | Value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 20 | 30 |
| Barry | 5 | 10 |

and i would like something as:

| Name | Index | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Value_1 | 20 |
| John | Value_2 | 30 |
| Barry | Value_1 | 5 |
| Barry | Value_2 | 10 |

Does pandas have any method in order to make this transformation ?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: please check this: `https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pandas-t-transpose/`

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'Barry'], 'Value_1': [20, 5], 'Value_2': [30, 10]})

df.melt(id_vars='Name', value_vars=['Value_1', 'Value_2'], var_name='1', value_name='2')
```

**Outputs:**

```
    Name    1         2
0   John    Value_1   20
1   Barry   Value_1   5
2   John    Value_2   30
3   Barry   Value_2   10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
(df.set_index('Name')
 .rename_axis('Index',axis=1)
 .stack()
 .rename('Value')
 .reset_index())
```